# Python - Better way for looping multidimensional dictionary

Tags: python, functional-programming

how I can change my code to use just one loop. I try to use .iteritems(), iterkeys() etc...

```
for user in data:
    for item in data[user]:
        start = seconds_since_midnight(
            data[user][item]['start']
        )
        end = seconds_since_midnight(
            data[user][item]['end']
        )
        overtime = end - start

        if overtime > eight_hours:
            if user not in result:
                if str(user) not in names.keys():
                    continue
                result[user] = {
                    'name': names[str(user)]['name'],
                    'overtime': []
                }

            result[user]['overtime'].append(overtime - eight_hours)
    try:
        result[user]['overtime'] = sum(result[user]['overtime'])
    except KeyError:
        pass

return sorted(
    result.items(),
    key=lambda result: result[1]['overtime'],
    reverse=True
)
```

> It creates structure like this:
>       data = {
>      'user_id': {
>      datetime.date(2013, 10, 1): {
>        'start': datetime.time(9, 0, 0),
>                   'end': datetime.time(17, 30, 0),
>               },
>               datetime.date(2013, 10, 2): {
>                   'start': datetime.time(8, 30, 0),
>                   'end': datetime.time(16, 45, 0),
>               },
>           }
>       }

Comment: Why do you want to have only one loop. As far as I can tell, you only access every element once. Thus, there is little or no gain in using only one loop, as long as you do not plan to execute the work in parallel threads/processes.

Comment: The asker might be motivated by the fact that "flat is better than nested". (Zen of Python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to remark is we can assume each user appears only once in `data` because it is a dictionary.

**Solution 1**

Now introduce these 2 functions:

```
def overtime(item):
    start = seconds_since_midnight(item['start'])
    end = seconds_since_midnight(item['end'])

    return end - start


def comp_hours(name, items):
    return {'name': name, 
            'overtime': sum(overtime(item) - 8 for item in items if overtime(item) > 8)}
```

Now do this dictionary comprehension:

```
result = {u: comp_hours(names[str(u)]['name'], i) for u, i in data.items() if str(u) in names}
result_filtered = {k: v for k, v in result.items() if v > 0}
```

You have to do the sorting yourself.

**Solution 2**

We modify our first solution.

Introduce functions

```
def total_overtime(items):
    return sum(overtime(item) - 8 for item in items if overtime(item) > 8)


def comp_hours_new(user, items):
    return {'name': names[str(user)]['name'], 'overtime': total_overtime(items)}


def condition(user, items):
    return str(user) in names and total_overtime(items) > 0
```

Then do this

```
{u: comp_hours_new(u, i) for u, i in data.items() if condition(u, i)}
```

With functional programming you would not have to compute `total_overtime` and `overtime` 2X.

After all this one was a classic case of this pattern

```
{k: f(k, v) for k, v in your_dict.items() if condition(k, v)}
```

**Solution 3**

To overcome waisting CPU time we modify our solution a bit and will work with generators.
Introduce functions

```
def condition_new(user, total_overtime_):
    return str(user) in names and total_overtime_ > 0


def comp_hours_new_new(user, total_overtime_):
    return {'name': names[str(user)]['name'], 'overtime': total_overtime_}
```

Now do

```
I = ((u, total_overtime(i)) for u, i in data.items())
{u: comp_hours_new_new(u, ttl_over) for u, ttl_over in I if condition_new(u, ttl_over)}
```

Comment: @DamianWysocki I forgotten to filter for users who do not have overtime, I fixed it however. You want to have another look.

Comment: thanks a lot for your solution its is very helpful for me ;)